# AngularJS Dropdown language select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

for a school project I am creating an application using AngularJS. I am trying to create a dropdown menu that sets the selected language using a button.

JS:

```
app.controller('NavCtrl',['$scope','$translate', function($scope,$translate){

    $scope.languages = [
        { language: "en", },
        { language: "nl" }
    ];

    $scope.selectedlanguage = $scope.languages[1];

    $scope.ChangeLanguage = function (lang) {
        $translate.use(lang);
    }

}])
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="NavCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedlanguage" 
            ng-change="option(this.selectedlanguage)" 
            ng-options="i.language for i in languages">
    </select>
    {{selectedlanguage.language}}
    <button class="button button-clear" 
            ng-click="ChangeLanguage('{{selectedlanguage.language}}')">
         Set language
    </button>
</div>
```

At the moment the button always sets my language to [1] (nl), how do I get it to set the language to the language selected in the dropdown menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see a few problems.

**First**, you don't need the `this.selectedLanguage` in your view, as `$scope` is automatically assumed as your context:

```
ng-change="option(selectedlanguage)"
```

**Second**, in your controller, you are setting `$scope.selectedlanguage` to an `i`, but then binding it to `i.language` in the view. To fix this, try:

```
ng-options="i as i.language for i in languages"
```

The `x as y` syntax lets you bind `x` to the model, while showing `y` for your dropdown label.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

**Third**, as @Matthew Berg points out, you don't need the `{{...}}` in you click handler:

```
ng-click="ChangeLanguage(selectedlanguage.language)"
```

Here's a plunkr with everything working:

http://plnkr.co/edit/YZf3vsKQEucOsKFLlYoQ?p=preview

Comment: This fixed everything! Thanks for the fast reply and helping me learn a bit more about JS :).

Answer (score 3):

No need to wrap it in `{{...}}`

```
<div ng-controller="NavCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedlanguage" 
            ng-change="option(this.selectedlanguage)" 
            ng-options="i.language for i in languages">
    </select>
    {{selectedlanguage.language}}
    <button class="button button-clear" 
            ng-click="ChangeLanguage(selectedlanguage)">
         Set language
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, your comment in combination with @Mike Chamberlain fixed my issue!

Comment: I will as soon as I have the needed reputation!

Answer (score 1):

use this code::::

```
  <div ng-controller="NavCtrl">
       <select ng-model="selectedlanguage" ng-change="option(selectedlanguage)" ng-options="i as i.language for i in languages"></select>
        {{selectedlanguage.language}}
       <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="ChangeLanguage(selectedlanguage)">Set language</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: This alone didn't work, but as @Mike Chamberlain pointed out parts of it were needed to fix the overall problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can you check lang value inside $scope.ChangeLanguage function? I think it is always {{selectedlanguage.language}}.

Change:
    "ChangeLanguage(selectedlanguage.language)"